# Creating a simple recursive descent expression parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, recursion

I am creating an simple descent expression evaluator that can evaluate simple math expressions using the Python Cookbook. (e. g `(2 + 3) * 7`)

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 111, in <module>
    print(evaluator.parse("2"))
  File "...", line 43, in parse
    self._advance()  # Load first lookahead token
  File "...", line 48, in _advance
    self.tok, self.nexttok = self.nexttok, next(self.tok, None)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not an iterator
```

My symbols:

```py
NUM = r"(?P<NUM>\d+)"
ADD = r"(?P<ADD>\+)"
SUB = r"(?P<SUB>-)"
MUL = r"(?P<MUL>\*)"
TRUEDIV = r"(?P<TRUEDIV>/)"
LEFTPAR = r"(?P<LEFTPAR>\()"
RIGHTPAR = r"(?P<RIGHTPAR>\))"
WS = r"(?P<WS>\s+)"

master_pat = re.compile("|".join([NUM, ADD, SUB, MUL, TRUEDIV,
                                  LEFTPAR, RIGHTPAR, WS]))
Token = namedtuple("Token", ["type", "value"])


def generate_tokens(text):
    scanner = master_pat.scanner(text)

    for match in iter(scanner.match, None):
        tok = Token(match.lastgroup, match.group())

        if tok.type != "WS":
            yield tok
```

My evaluator:

```py
class Evaluator:
    def parse(self, text):
        self.tokens = generate_tokens(text)
        self.tok = None  # Last symbol covered
        self.nexttok = None  # Next symbol tokenized
        self._advance()  # Load first lookahead token
        return self.expr()

    def _advance(self):
        """Advance one token ahead."""
        self.tok, self.nexttok = self.nexttok, next(self.tok, None)

    def _accept(self, toktype):
        """Test and consume the next token if it matches toktype."""
        if self.nexttok and self.nexttok.type == toktype:
            self._advance()
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def _expect(self, toktype):
        """Consume next token if it matches toktype or raise SyntaxError"""
        if not self._accept(toktype):
            raise SyntaxError("invalid syntax")

    # Grammer rules

    def expr(self):
        """expression ::= term { ('+'|'-') term }*"""

        exprval = self.term()

        while self._accept("ADD") or self._accept("SUB"):
            op = self.tok.type
            right = self.term()

            if op == "ADD":
                exprval += right
            elif op == "SUB":
                exprval -= right

        return exprval

    def term(self):
        """factor ::= NUM | ( expr )"""

        termval = self.factor()

        while self._accept("MUL") or self._accept("TRUEDIV"):
            op = self.tok.type
            right = self.factor()

            if op == "MUL":
                termval *= right
            elif op == "TRUEDIV":
                termval /= right

        return termval

    def factor(self):
        """factor ::= NUM | ( expr )"""

        if self._accept("NUM"):
            return int(self.tok.value)
        elif self._accept("LEFTPAR"):
            exprval = self.expr()
            self._expect("RIGHTPAR")
            return exprval
        else:
            raise SyntaxError("invalid syntax")
```

However, when I tried to parse *anything* I got the error mentioned above.
How can I make a actually working recursive descent parser?

Comment: Where is `self.tok` ever set to anything other than `None`?

Comment: `self.tok, self.nexttok = self.nexttok, next(self.tok, None)`

Comment: But that depends on `self.tok`already being not None -->  `next(self.tok, None)` this is the line that is raising the exception. What happens the first time it is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that currently, `self.tok` is never set to anything other then `None`, hence the error. Just changing `self.tok` to `self.tokens` solves the problem.

```py
    def _advance(self):
        """Advance one token ahead."""
        self.tok, self.nexttok = self.nexttok, next(self.tokens, None)
```